# Can't find branch name in git config file

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, gitlab-ci

I have used `gitlabSourceBranch` as Branch Specifier (blank for 'any') in the Jenkins Job configuration page, like this:

**Note:** Value will be passed to the variable "gitlabSourceBranch" when trigger a job in Jenkins.

[image]

Using `gitlabSourceBranch`, I am able to checkout the required git source, but unable to find the branch name in the git config file or in any of the files in .git folder in the Jenkins workspace location.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Chris-joe, that is because when Jenkins checkouts a branch what it does it by default is to checkout the commit pointed by that branch. You will probably see something like this in the log:

```
git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}
```

that way it gets the commit pointed by that branch, and below that:

```
git checkout -f eea1d126120081a28b4d4537e09b467ea3cac33c
```

This is how Jenkins does the checkout.

You can define a local branch to checkout if you configure under *Additional Behaviors | Check out to specific local branch* the branch name you want. 
[image]

Then you should see in the logs:

```
git checkout -b my-branch eea1d126120081a28b4d4537e09b467ea3cac33c
```